# No such file or directory when i load image

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When loading an image from a form, an error is triggered: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '... \ pictures \ foto.jpg'",
but if i load from database then everything works well

file `views.py`:

```
elif "ProfileUpdateForm" in request.POST:
    form=ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        profile=Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        profile.avtor=form.cleaned_data.get('avtor')
        profile.save()
        obj=Profile.objects.get(user__username=self.request.user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('profile',kwargs={'slug': obj.slug},))
```

file `forms.py`:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields=('avtor',)
        widgets={'avtor': forms.FileInput(),}
```

file `models.py`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,verbose_name="Пользователь",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avtor=models.ImageField(verbose_name="Аватарка",default='user_images/default.jpg', upload_to='user_images',blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwards):
        image = Image.open(self.avtor.path)

        if image.height > 256 or image.width > 256:
            resize = (256, 256)
            image.thumbnail(resize)
            image.save(self.avtor.path)

        return super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwards)
```

file `profile.html`:

```
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ ProfileUpdateForm.as_p }}
          <input name="ProfileUpdateForm" class="input-button" type="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem appears when you are overriding the save method of your model to resize the image. I would recommend installing and using django-stdimage library (https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage). This should make your life so much easier. After installation, you will just need to create a field this way:

```
from stdimage import StdImageField

class Profile(models.Model):
    avtor = StdImageField(verbose_name="Аватарка", default='user_images/default.jpg', upload_to='user_images', blank=True,  variations={'resized': {'width': 256, 'height': 256}})
    ...
```

Use variations to set up the resized image. You can access the image in the template this way: `avtor.resized`

Comment: File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 247, in __init__   
    super().__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'

Comment: Why doesn't it work? I connected everything correctly, because the validation works and I get the error: "The image you uploaded is too large. The required maximum resolution is: 256x256 px.", But resize does not work (

Comment: Please see the edits of my answer. I've added ```variations={'thumbnail': {'width': 256, 'height': 256}}``` instead of ```size```.

Comment: Can not work because of this line? widgets = {'after': forms.FileInput (),}

Comment: That may be a reason. Also, did you remove save method from the model?